# MySQL-devel installed but cannot be detected by rpmbuild?

Tags: rpm

I've been trying to build `apr-util-1.5.2` on CentOS 6 64bit. I've ran into this problem:

```
# rpmbuild -tb apr-util-1.5.2.tar.bz2
error: Failed build dependencies:
        mysql-devel is needed by apr-util-1.5.2-1.x86_64
```

now the problem is that I already have MySQL installed, but using the binaries.

```
# yum list installed | grep My
MySQL-devel.x86_64                    5.6.13-1.linux_glibc2.5          installed
```

I have configured the `/usr/local/mysql/bin` path and the `/usr/local/mysql/lib` lib path and yet I cannot build the tarball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build `apr-util` using the development headers included in Oracle's MySQL Community Edition, you need to modify the `apr-util.spec` file to reference it:

```
$ diff -ub apr-util.spec~ apr-util.spec
--- apr-util.spec~      2013-03-30 21:30:12.000000000 +0100
+++ apr-util.spec       2013-08-10 09:32:09.507297069 +0200
@@ -53,7 +53,7 @@
 %package mysql
 Group: Development/Libraries
 Summary: APR utility library MySQL DBD driver
-BuildRequires: mysql-devel
+BuildRequires: MySQL-devel
 Requires: apr-util = %{version}-%{release}

 %description mysql
```

Comment: it's works now after updating the spec file . However i got new problem haha .

Comment: Actually, you will have a lots of problem in such environment

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL-devel.x86_64                    5.6.13-1.linux_glibc2.5          installed

it is not builtin package. Where did you get it?

You need to install mysql-devel via yum

```
# yum install mysql-devel
```

If you REALLY need to use mysql-5.6.x you could try to use IUS Community repo

```
# yum --enablerepo=ius-dev search mysql56
mysql56-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package mysql56
mysql56.x86_64 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
mysql56-bench.x86_64 : MySQL benchmark scripts and data
mysql56-devel.x86_64 : Files for development of MySQL applications
mysql56-embedded.x86_64 : MySQL as an embeddable library
mysql56-embedded-devel.x86_64 : Development files for MySQL as an embeddable library
mysql56-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for MySQL clients
mysql56-server.x86_64 : The MySQL server and related files
mysql56-test.x86_64 : The test suite distributed with MySQL
```

Comment: I got the MySQl binaries from the offical MySQL website . I am using the community edition . Also ,  if i try to install mysql-devel via yum install , it will complain of an error  : Error: mysql-devel conflicts with MySQL-devel.

Comment: Oh yeah , i cannot reinstall MySQL since this is production mode already .

Answer (score 0):

it's case sensitive: `MySQL-devel` is not `mysql-devel`.
First one can be downloaded from mysql.com, second one is from centos repo :)